# Is there a way to apply a function with multiple arguments over two data frames in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, iteration, purrr

I want to write a function to replace values of "+" in the "values" data.frame with the corresponding value in the "others" data.frame.

```
values <- data.frame(A = c("banana", "orange", "apple", "pear", "+"),
                 B = c("apple", "+", "banana", "melon", "orange"))

others <- data.frame(A = c("", "", "", "", "apple"),
                     B = c("", "pear", "", "", ""))

names <- c("A", "B")

#function to replace values of "+" with corresponding value in other data.frame
replace_with_other <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(x == "+", y, x)
}
```

This function works like this, but I can't figure out how to iterate over all the values in "names."

```
#this works and gives the desired output
replace_with_other(values$A, others$A)

#but when I try to iterate over all the names, I get an error message.
map(names, replace_with_other(values, others))
```

For the first name "A" the output I'm looking for is

```
"banana" "orange" "apple"  "pear"   "apple"
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work for you?

````
> Map(replace_with_other, values[names], others[names])
$A
[1] "banana" "orange" "apple"  "pear"   "apple"

$B
[1] "apple"  "pear"   "banana" "melon"  "orange"```
````

Answer (score 3):

We can do this within `dplyr` itself. As the column names are the same, we could loop `across` all the columns in 'values', extract the corresponding columns from 'others' using `cur_column()` (returns the column name within `across`), replace the `""` with `NA` (`na_if`) and use `coalesce` so that it will replace with first non-NA elementwise

```
library(dplyr)
values %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ 
       coalesce(na_if(others[[cur_column()]], ""), .)))
#    A      B
#1 banana  apple
#2 orange   pear
#3  apple banana
#4   pear  melon
#5  apple orange
```

---

Or may use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(values[names], others[names], replace_with_other)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it this way:

```
replace_with_other <- function(x, y, name) {
  ifelse(x[[name]] == "+", y[[name]], x[[name]])
}

purrr::map(names, ~replace_with_other(values, others, .x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "banana" "orange" "apple"  "pear"   "apple" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "apple"  "pear"   "banana" "melon"  "orange"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest something different, maybe it helps for all your data:

```
# function that replace + with corrispondent values in another df
func <- function(x, y){

# convert as matrix the two imputs
a <- as.matrix(x)
b <- as.matrix(y)

# paste0 them i.e. merge in one matrix
ab <- matrix(paste0(a, b), nrow = nrow(a))

# replace the + with nothing and convert as df
ab <- data.frame(gsub("\\+", "", ab))

# colnames from the first input
colnames(ab) <- colnames(x)

# print the output
print(ab)}


func(values, others)

       A      B
1 banana  apple
2 orange   pear
3  apple banana
4   pear  melon
5  apple orange
```

Answer (score 2):

Find the position where `'+'` is present in `values` and replace it with corresponding value from `others`.

```
mat <- values == '+'
values[mat] <- others[mat]
values

#       A      B
#1 banana  apple
#2 orange   pear
#3  apple banana
#4   pear  melon
#5  apple orange
```

This requires both the dataframes having column names in the same order as shared in the example data. If they are not you can rearrange the columns with.

```
values <- values[names]
others <- others[names]
```